# No react native icon on device to unistall app

Tags: android, react-native

When developing my app, how can i uninstall my app? I cannot see an icon on my device to uninstall, any ideas?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: it is uninstalled same way as any other app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings>Applications>All Apps You can find an app with the green android icon. Find it and uninstall. If its not working, then run your app > open recent apps > press and hold the app icon > tap app info > then Uninstall.

Comment: Also just holding it and dragging it into the trash can would delete it, depends on the android version